# terraform for_each implementation with values from .tfvars

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.14.7

I have a common.tfvars file with definition of a variables as:

```
bqtable_date_partition = [
  { dataset = "d1", table_name = "d1-t1", part_col = "partition_date",
  part_type = "DAY", schema_file = "data_tables/d1-t1.json" },

  { dataset = "d1", table_name = "d1-t2", part_col = "tran_dt",
  part_type = "DAY", schema_file = "data_tables/d1-t2.json" },

  { dataset = "d2", table_name = "d2-t1", part_col = "tran_dt",
  part_type = "DAY", schema_file = "data_tables/d2-t1.json" },
]
```

and I am referencing this var in main.tf file with following resource defintion:

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "bq_tables_dt_pt" {
  count      = length(var.bqtable_date_partition)
  project    = var.project_id
  dataset_id = "${var.bqtable_date_partition[count.index].dataset}_${var.env}"
  table_id   = var.bqtable_date_partition[count.index].table_name
  time_partitioning {
    type  = var.bqtable_date_partition[count.index].part_type
    field = var.bqtable_date_partition[count.index].part_col
  }
  schema     = file("${path.module}/tables/${var.bqtable_date_partition[count.index].schema_file}")
  depends_on = [google_bigquery_dataset.crte_bq_dataset]
  labels = {
    env        = var.env
    ind        = "corp"
  }
}
```

I want to change the resource definition to use "for_each" instead of "count" to loop through the list:

My motive to change from count to for_each is to eliminate the dependency on the order in which I have written the elements of the variable "bqtable_date_partition "

I did this:

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "bq_tables_dt_pt" {
  for_each   = var.bqtable_date_partition
  project    = var.project_id
  dataset_id = "${each.value.dataset}_${var.env}"
  table_id   = each.value.table_name
  time_partitioning {
    type  = each.value.part_type
    field = each.value.part_col
  }
  schema     = file("${path.module}/tables/${each.value.schema_file}")
  depends_on = [google_bigquery_dataset.crte_bq_dataset]
  labels = {
    env        = var.env
    ind        = "corp"
  }
}
```

I got the following error as expected:

> The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each"
> argument must be a map or set of strings, and you have provided a
> value of type list of map of string.

Can anyone help me with what changes I need do to make in the resource definition to use "for_each"?

Terraform version - 0.14.x

Answer (score 1):

Error says it only accepts the map or set of strings. So we have to convert our input variable to either map or set of strings.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "bq_tables_dt_pt" {
  for_each   = { for index, data_partition in var.bqtable_date_partition : index => data_partition }
  project    = var.project_id
  dataset_id = "${each.value.dataset}_${var.env}"
  table_id   = each.value.table_name
  time_partitioning {
    type  = each.value.part_type
    field = each.value.part_col
  }
  schema     = file("${path.module}/tables/${each.value.schema_file}")
  depends_on = [google_bigquery_dataset.crte_bq_dataset]
  labels = {
    env = var.env
    ind = "corp"
  }
}
```

So basically, here we are converting for_each input into the following format. and only referencing value in from newly created map.

```
{
  "0" = {
    "dataset" = "d1"
    "part_col" = "partition_date"
    "part_type" = "DAY"
    "schema_file" = "data_tables/d1-t1.json"
    "table_name" = "d1-t1"
  }
  "1" = {
    "dataset" = "d1"
    "part_col" = "tran_dt"
    "part_type" = "DAY"
    "schema_file" = "data_tables/d1-t2.json"
    "table_name" = "d1-t2"
  }
  "2" = {
    "dataset" = "d2"
    "part_col" = "tran_dt"
    "part_type" = "DAY"
    "schema_file" = "data_tables/d2-t1.json"
    "table_name" = "d2-t1"
  }
}
```

Comment: My motive to change from count to for_each is to eliminate the dependency on the order in which I have written the elements of variable "bqtable_date_partition ".  I tried your solution but in this too I feel by seeing the plan, the order will matter and in my plan, it is saying it will destroy 3 resources and create 3.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main requirements for using `for_each`:

- You must have a collection that has one element for each resource instance you want to declare.
- There must be some way to derive a unique identifier from each element of that collection which Terraform will then use as the unique instance key.

It seems like your collection meets both of these criteria, assuming that `table_name` is a unique string across all of those values, and so all that remains is to project the collection into a map so that Terraform can see from the keys that you intend to use the `table_name` for the unique tracking keys:

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "bq_tables_dt_pt" {
  for_each = {
    for o in var.bqtable_date_partition : o.table_name => o
  }

  # ...
}
```

Here I've used a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html) to project from a sequence to a mapping, where each element is identified by the value in its `table_name` attribute.

---

If you are in a situation where you're able to change the interface to this module then you could simplify things by changing the variable's declaration to expect a map instead of a list, which would then avoid the need for the projection and make it explicit to the module *caller* that the table IDs must be unique:

```
variable "bqtable_date_partition" {
  type = map(object({
    dataset     = string
    part_col    = string
    part_type   = string
    schema_file = string
  }))
}
```

Then you could just assign `var.bqtable_date_partition` directly to `for_each` as you tried before, because it'll already be of a suitable type. But would also require changing your calling module to pass a map value instead of a list value, and so this might not be practical if your module has many callers that would all need to be updated to remain compatible.